# How to manually set the base address of a pointer in IDA?

Tags: ida

IDA autodetected some kind of offset like this:

```
mov     bx, word ptr (aSomeString+8)[di]
```

I want to set the base address to something else, like for example:

```
mov     bx, word ptr (glb_AnArray-6)[di]
```

because the pointer is actually a pointer to an array (of elements with size 6) that is indexed starting from 1. Bonus points if it's possible to transform it to something like this:

```
mov     bx, word ptr glb_AnArray[di+6]
```

So the question is: How can I tell IDA to take a specific address as base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> should be what you're looking for (highlight aSomeString before you press the key combo).

Alternatively you can use the menu `Edit`->`Operand type`->`Offset`->`Offset user defined`